# Proper way to manage the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am using mutable array . I am not sure is this a correct way of managing the array. I tried to learn the memory management basics,but I found it too difficult to grasp. What I am doing is

declaring the array at the interface

```
@interface myVC()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *substrings; // if I use weak attribute here,does it change anything?
 @end


 -(void)myMethod{

  // initializing the array
   _substrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   //storing some data into it
    [_substrings addObject:@"hello"];

    //do something with the data in that array
       //call another method which gets the data from this same array and do some operations there
            [self method2];-----> // I access data from the array like, x=[_substrings objectatindex:0];

     //finally, remove the items in the array
      [_substrings removeObject:@"hello"];

       //and again start the process as mentioned here


    }
```

This is what I am thinking to do. Is this a proper way of declaring and accesssing and managing the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it will work, however I would recommend to access to this array using property getter/setter. This way if you will ever need to create a custom getter/setter you will not need to refactor all your code.

```
@interface myVC()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *substrings; 
@end


-(void)myMethod{

  // initializing the array
  _substrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  //storing some data into it
  [self.substrings addObject:@"hello"];

  [self method2];-----> // I access data from the array like, x=[self.substrings objectatindex:0];

  //finally, remove the items in the array
  [self.substrings removeObject:@"hello"];
}
```